# Not all reviews visible

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an app to Google Play.
From developer console I see there are 8 reviews.
But only 5 of them are displayed in Google Play, and they are not last 5, just random.
How can I force it show all reviews?

Answer (score 0):

Use [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to see all ratings. Simply download all ratings as described, the related csv file will contain direct links to the reviews. You will be able to see details like user name, used device, app version, etc. - and you can reply to them!

UPDATE: Google is no longer exporting links to reviews with no comments, starting from November 3rd, 2015. No reason was provided.